# Getting screen resolution of 545 X 320 in Moto Xoom

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, screen-resolution, motorola, motorola-droid

After updating Moto Xoom to 3.2, i am getting screen resolution of 545 X 320 instead of 1280 X 800?

Is this normal?

Comment: Nope abnormal, I have a Xyboard and Xoom it has the sme old settings of 1280x800. Try restarting the device and check if you have pressed the zoom button on the bottom right hand corder.

Comment: please select the answer

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in manifest file and check if it solve your problem or not:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Put it in **manifest** element.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by Putting following lines of code and compiling with Android 3.2 target.

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
             android:smallScreens="true"
             android:anyDensity="true"
             android:normalScreens="true"
             android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```